# SQL finding number of users in consecutive months in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an table with the following columns

```
email        ----        created at
abc@gmail.com        2019-12-12 16:03:34
rp@gamil.com         2019-11-12 16:03:34
abc@gmail.com        2020-1-12 16:03:34
er@gmail.com         2020-1-12 16:03:34
```

I want to design a query that return the back number of emails that registered in consecutive 2 months. I am no novice with queries and have been struggling to come up with a query for this.

For the above the query `abc@gmail.com` was registered twice in consecutive months

Comment: So basically you want email count for each month?

Comment: Did one of these answers solve your problem? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `EXISTS` query to check if an email exists that also had a registration in the previous month:

```
SELECT DISTINCT email
FROM yourtable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM yourtable t2
              WHERE t2.email = t1.email 
                AND DATE_FORMAT(t2.createdat, '%Y%m') = DATE_FORMAT(t1.createdat - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y%m'))
```

Output for your sample data

```
abc@gmail.com
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pVgf8ZKHB15TGDL3KVCd1j/3)

We use `DISTINCT` so we don't get multiple copies of the same email if an email address is registered in more than one consecutive month.

Comment: This only returns results for single consecutive months, not two consecutive months.

Comment: @Dai that is what OP wants, take a look at the sample data and expected output in the question

Comment: Ah, sorry! My mistake!

Comment: Does this query handle the case where Month 1 is December 2019 and Month 2 is January 2020? I don't see the `YEAR` being included in your comparison.

Comment: @Dai it did, but not correctly as January 2020 and December 2018 would have been considered consecutive. thanks for pointing that out, I've corrected it

Answer (score 0):

By doing a self-join for `Month + 1` and `email` (and also taking December-to-January transitions into account) this should work:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            email,
            YEAR( created ) AS createdYear,
            MONTH( created ) AS createdMonth
        FROM
            table
    ) AS t

    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            email,
            YEAR( created ) AS createdYear,
            MONTH( created ) AS createdMonth
        FROM
            table
    ) AS monthPlus1 ON 
        t.email = monthPlus1.email
        AND
        (
            (
                t.createdMonth = monthPlus1.createdMonth + 1
                AND
                t.createdYear = monthPlus1.createdYear
            )
            OR
            (
                t.createdMonth = 12
                AND
                monthPlus1.createdMonth = 1
                AND
                t.createdYear + 1 = monthPlus1.createdYear
            )
        )
```

The date logic in this query is a bit gnarly - it can probably be improved by representing the month as a single `date` value or integer months-since-epoc rather than a `year + month` tuple.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()`.  If this occurs, then `lag()` will be in two adjacent months.

```
select t.email
from (select t.*
             lag(created_at) over (partition by t.email order by created_at) as prev_created_at
      from t
     ) t
where extract(year_month from created_at) = extract(year_month from (prev_created_at + interval 1 month));
```

You may need `select distinct`, if this can occur multiple times.